# Features of different kinds of path-dependent types in scala

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

Suppose there is a trait:

```
trait OuterTrait {
  type InnerType
}
```

Now we can write non-generic function `someAlgo`:

```
def pairToString[S, U](x: S, y: U): String = 
  "{" + y.toString + " in " + x.toString + "}"

def pairPrintln[S, U](x: S, y: U) {
  println(pairToString(x, y))
}

def someAlgo(x: OuterTrait)(y: x.InnerType): x.InnerType = {
  pairPrintln(x, y)
  y
}
```

and series of generic functions:

```
def someAlgoObjObj[T <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: x.InnerType): x.InnerType = {
  pairPrintln(x, y)
  y
}

def someAlgoObjType[T <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: x.InnerType): T#InnerType = {
  pairPrintln(x, y)
  y
}

def someAlgoTypeType[T <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: T#InnerType): T#InnerType = {
  pairPrintln(x, y)
  y
}
```

And one more generic function doesn't compile:

```
def someAlgoTypeObj[T <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: T#InnerType): x.InnerType = {
  pairPrintln(x, y)
  y
}
```

It seems that:
1) `someAlgo` and `someAlgoObjObj` are the most correct functions;
2) and there is no sense to use generic function in this example at all.

And I would like to clarify some differences between generic functions above. Please, correct me, If I make errors.

So as I understand type `T` corresponds to *static* type of `x` (call it `X`) or explicit type of generic call (I mean `algo[Int]` for instance). That's why `T#InnerType` corresponds to type in declaration of type `X`. But `x.InnerType` also corresponds to `InnerType` of *static* type of `x`. Where is the difference?

Further... `someAlgoObjType` compiles, so it seems that `x.InnerType` must be *subtype* of `T#InnerType`. Then it is OK that `someAlgoTypeObj` doesn't compile, since we can't make downcast implicitly. Though we can rewrite last one:

```
def someAlgoTypeObj[T <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: T#InnerType): x.InnerType = {
  pairPrintln(x, y)
  y.asInstanceOf[x.InnerType]
}
```

**UPD1:** I found one difference between `someAlgoObjObj` and `someAlgoTypeType` if use them with explicit type parameter. If we write some class extending `OuterTrait`:

```
class OuterIntClass extends OuterTrait{
  type InnerType = Int
}
val x: OuterIntClass = new OuterIntClass()
val y: Int = 5
```

Then:

```
someAlgoObjObj[OuterTrait](x)(y) // OK
```

and next call doesn't work:

```
someAlgoTypeType[OuterTrait](x)(y)
```

Comment: there is a great [blogpost](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/13/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-13-path-dependent-types.html) on PDT, you should definitely read it

Comment: Thank you, it's interesting. But I still have a problem with `T#InnerType`...

Answer (score 0):

`T#InnerType` means "A InnerType belonging *in some* T" while `x.InnerType` means "A InnerType belonging *in a given* x (of type OuterTrait)".

The key here in understanding these is *in some T* vs *in a given x*. You can interpret *in some* as *some T but we don't which T instance*, meaning that in a two Ts aren't necessarily the same, so, T#InnerType can't be proven to be equal to another T#InnerType.

Let's analyze the signatures:

```
/* 1 */ def someAlgoObjObj[T <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: x.InnerType): x.InnerType = ???
/* 2 */ def someAlgoObjType[T <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: x.InnerType): T#InnerType = ???
/* 3 */ def someAlgoTypeType[T <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: T#InnerType): T#InnerType = ???
```

1. Given x and InnerType belonging in *this x* returns the its InnerType.
2. Given x and InnerType belonging in *this x* returns InnerType belonging to *some T* , meaning a *some T* is not necessarily the same instance as x.
3. Given x and InnerType belonging to *some T* returns InnerType belonging to *some T*

Now for the forth one:

```
def someAlgoTypeObj[T <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: T#InnerType): x.InnerType = y
```

The signature reads: given x and InnerType belonging to *some T*, returns the InnerType belonging to *this x*. But in the implementation, we try to return y, which belongs to a T that's not necessarily the same as x, hence the compiler complains.

Comment: But _some type_ `T` propagates on the whole function signature. So we have _some type_ `T` and parameter `x` of _this some type_ `T`. You say «Given x and InnerType belonging in this x returns InnerType belonging to some T , meaning a some T is not necessarily the same instance as x.» Not the same — may be, but type of `x` must be subtype of `T`.

Comment: I mean that when we call some instance of generic function we have the same instance `Q` of `T` everywhere in our function. And since `x: Q`, `x.InnerType` can't absolutely differ from `Q#InnerType`.

Comment: You are missing the point. In `(x: T)(y: T#InnerType)`, the Ts here denote different instances - not necessarily different, but the compiler can't make that distinction. The compiler can only rely on information you provide, and in this case since x.InnerType and y can be different it assumes it is fact different.

Comment: In which way could they be different? It is true for `def algo[T <: OuterTrait, S <: OuterTrait](x: T)(y: S#InnerType)` — different type parameters. But type parameter `T` is the same everywhere in the function. Otherwise identical function wouldn't compile: `def id[T](x: T): T = x` like `def id[T, S](x: T): S = x`.

Answer (score 0):

Little note about **update**.

```
someAlgoTypeType[OuterTrait](x)(y)
```

Failes because your method signature tells that it expects its `y` parameter to conform to the type `T#InnerType` and your `y.type` is Int. To make it work you should change it's type to the following:

```
class OuterIntClass extends OuterTrait{
  type InnerType = Int
}
val x: OuterIntClass = new OuterIntClass()
val y: x.InnerType = 5
```

Now `y`'s type satisfies type projection `T#InnerType` and `someAlgoTypeType[OuterTrait](x)(y)` compiles